# Pure CSS form styling with columns?

Tags: css, forms

I have a form that I need styled to have 2, 4, and 6 columns. I named my classes col2, col4, and col6 respectively. I am having a lot of trouble especially with vertical alignment and the columns themselves. Can anyone help with this?

```
<div id="fieldset1" class="col2">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Living Room </legend>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm122">Bar, Portable</label>
                <input name="SingleForm122" type="text" id="SingleForm122" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm123">Bookcase</label>
                <input name="SingleForm123" type="text" id="SingleForm123" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm124">Bookshelves, Sectional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm124" type="text" id="SingleForm124" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm125">Cabinet, Curio</label>
                <input name="SingleForm125" type="text" id="SingleForm125" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm126">Chair, Arm</label>
                <input name="SingleForm126" type="text" id="SingleForm126" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm127">Chair, Occasional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm127" type="text" id="SingleForm127" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm128">Chair, Overstuffed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm128" type="text" id="SingleForm128" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm129">Chair, Rocker</label>
                <input name="SingleForm129" type="text" id="SingleForm129" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm130">Chair, Straight</label>
                <input name="SingleForm130" type="text" id="SingleForm130" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm131">Clock, Grandfather</label>
                <input name="SingleForm131" type="text" id="SingleForm131" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm132">Day Bed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm132" type="text" id="SingleForm132" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm133">Desk, Small</label>
                <input name="SingleForm133" type="text" id="SingleForm133" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
<div id="fieldset2" class="col4">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Living Room </legend>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm122">Bar, Portable</label>
                <input name="SingleForm122" type="text" id="Text1" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm123">Bookcase</label>
                <input name="SingleForm123" type="text" id="Text2" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm124">Bookshelves, Sectional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm124" type="text" id="Text3" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm125">Cabinet, Curio</label>
                <input name="SingleForm125" type="text" id="Text4" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm126">Chair, Arm</label>
                <input name="SingleForm126" type="text" id="Text5" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm127">Chair, Occasional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm127" type="text" id="Text6" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm128">Chair, Overstuffed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm128" type="text" id="Text7" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm129">Chair, Rocker</label>
                <input name="SingleForm129" type="text" id="Text8" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm130">Chair, Straight</label>
                <input name="SingleForm130" type="text" id="Text9" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm131">Clock, Grandfather</label>
                <input name="SingleForm131" type="text" id="Text10" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm132">Day Bed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm132" type="text" id="Text11" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm133">Desk, Small</label>
                <input name="SingleForm133" type="text" id="Text12" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm134">Desk, Secretary</label>
                <input name="SingleForm134" type="text" id="Text13" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm135">Foot Stool</label>
                <input name="SingleForm135" type="text" id="Text14" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm136">Hide-a-bed or Studio Couch</label>
                <input name="SingleForm136" type="text" id="Text15" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm137">Lamp, Floor or Pole</label>
                <input name="SingleForm137" type="text" id="Text16" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
<div id="fieldset3" class="col6">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Living Room </legend>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm122">Bar, Portable</label>
                <input name="SingleForm122" type="text" id="Text25" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm123">Bookcase</label>
                <input name="SingleForm123" type="text" id="Text26" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm124">Bookshelves, Sectional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm124" type="text" id="Text27" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm125">Cabinet, Curio</label>
                <input name="SingleForm125" type="text" id="Text28" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm126">Chair, Arm</label>
                <input name="SingleForm126" type="text" id="Text29" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm127">Chair, Occasional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm127" type="text" id="Text30" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm128">Chair, Overstuffed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm128" type="text" id="Text31" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm129">Chair, Rocker</label>
                <input name="SingleForm129" type="text" id="Text32" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm130">Chair, Straight</label>
                <input name="SingleForm130" type="text" id="Text33" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm131">Clock, Grandfather</label>
                <input name="SingleForm131" type="text" id="Text34" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm132">Day Bed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm132" type="text" id="Text35" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm133">Desk, Small</label>
                <input name="SingleForm133" type="text" id="Text36" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm134">Desk, Secretary</label>
                <input name="SingleForm134" type="text" id="Text37" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm135">Foot Stool</label>
                <input name="SingleForm135" type="text" id="Text38" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm136">Hide-a-bed or Studio Couch</label>
                <input name="SingleForm136" type="text" id="Text39" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm137">Lamp, Floor or Pole</label>
                <input name="SingleForm137" type="text" id="Text40" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm138">Music Cabinet</label>
                <input name="SingleForm138" type="text" id="Text41" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm139">Rug, Large Roll</label>
                <input name="SingleForm139" type="text" id="Text42" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm140">Rug, Small Roll</label>
                <input name="SingleForm140" type="text" id="Text43" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm141">Sofa, 2 Cushions</label>
                <input name="SingleForm141" type="text" id="Text44" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm142">Sofa, 3 Cushions</label>
                <input name="SingleForm142" type="text" id="Text45" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm143">Sofa, 4 Cushions</label>
                <input name="SingleForm143" type="text" id="Text46" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm144">Sofa, Sectional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm144" type="text" id="Text47" class="inputText" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm145">Table, Coffee, End or Night</label>
                <input name="SingleForm145" type="text" id="Text48" class="inputText" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the current CSS as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use tables? You have laid everything out like tables (rowContainer = tr, rowItem = td). All you need to do is change the div tags into table, tr and td tags.

Tables aren't evil, not if you want to display stuff in a tabular fashion. If tables are the easiest way to align things the way you want, then use tables.

Comment: Tables are not for displaying stuff in a tabular fashion. They're for displaying tabular data.

Comment: Says who? some guy on the internet? Why is creating a DOM tree with the exact same layout as tables better than tables? The simplest way to arrange divs in a grid would be to use display: table, table-row and table-cell (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop). But whats the point of creating something that already exists? How much better is your page with lots of divs instead of lots of tables? Who views your page without CSS, and who cares if that page without CSS has a table in it?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues too. I ended up using Blueprint CSS (or alternatively 960.gs) which simplifies creation of column based layouts greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use tables for virtually all forms, small and large. It's just so much easier to format and you get away with so much less code.

I recommend you use tables and solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you're after, but if you're after a three columns layout with aligned borders, particularly the bottom one, and you have an unbalanced content, you can wrap your columns in a div (colWrapper), get rid of the div clearing on both sides, and remove the border applied to your fieldsets. By applying a overflow:hidden to the wrapper, then forcing a long margin (-3000px) in one way, and a long padding (3000px) to the columns, you can then apply the border to your columns and get the desired effect. It is also known as the "holy grail".

```
.col2,.col4,.col6{float:left;}
div > fieldset{border:none;}
#colWrapper{overflow:hidden;border-bottom:1px solid black;}
#colWrapper > div {border:1px solid; margin-bottom:-3000px;padding-bottom:3000px;}
.col2,.col4{border-right:none;}
```

Your HTML would be like:

```
<div id="colWrapper"><div id="fieldset1" class="col2">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Living Room </legend>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm122">Bar, Portable</label>
                <input name="SingleForm122" id="SingleForm122" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm123">Bookcase</label>
                <input name="SingleForm123" id="SingleForm123" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm124">Bookshelves, Sectional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm124" id="SingleForm124" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm125">Cabinet, Curio</label>
                <input name="SingleForm125" id="SingleForm125" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm126">Chair, Arm</label>
                <input name="SingleForm126" id="SingleForm126" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm127">Chair, Occasional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm127" id="SingleForm127" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm128">Chair, Overstuffed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm128" id="SingleForm128" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm129">Chair, Rocker</label>
                <input name="SingleForm129" id="SingleForm129" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm130">Chair, Straight</label>
                <input name="SingleForm130" id="SingleForm130" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm131">Clock, Grandfather</label>
                <input name="SingleForm131" id="SingleForm131" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm132">Day Bed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm132" id="SingleForm132" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm133">Desk, Small</label>
                <input name="SingleForm133" id="SingleForm133" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="fieldset2" class="col4">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Living Room </legend>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm122">Bar, Portable</label>
                <input name="SingleForm122" id="Text1" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm123">Bookcase</label>
                <input name="SingleForm123" id="Text2" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm124">Bookshelves, Sectional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm124" id="Text3" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm125">Cabinet, Curio</label>
                <input name="SingleForm125" id="Text4" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm126">Chair, Arm</label>
                <input name="SingleForm126" id="Text5" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm127">Chair, Occasional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm127" id="Text6" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm128">Chair, Overstuffed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm128" id="Text7" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm129">Chair, Rocker</label>
                <input name="SingleForm129" id="Text8" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm130">Chair, Straight</label>
                <input name="SingleForm130" id="Text9" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm131">Clock, Grandfather</label>
                <input name="SingleForm131" id="Text10" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm132">Day Bed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm132" id="Text11" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm133">Desk, Small</label>
                <input name="SingleForm133" id="Text12" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm134">Desk, Secretary</label>
                <input name="SingleForm134" id="Text13" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm135">Foot Stool</label>
                <input name="SingleForm135" id="Text14" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm136">Hide-a-bed or Studio Couch</label>
                <input name="SingleForm136" id="Text15" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm137">Lamp, Floor or Pole</label>
                <input name="SingleForm137" id="Text16" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="fieldset3" class="col6">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Living Room </legend>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm122">Bar, Portable</label>
                <input name="SingleForm122" id="Text25" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm123">Bookcase</label>
                <input name="SingleForm123" id="Text26" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm124">Bookshelves, Sectional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm124" id="Text27" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm125">Cabinet, Curio</label>
                <input name="SingleForm125" id="Text28" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm126">Chair, Arm</label>
                <input name="SingleForm126" id="Text29" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm127">Chair, Occasional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm127" id="Text30" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm128">Chair, Overstuffed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm128" id="Text31" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm129">Chair, Rocker</label>
                <input name="SingleForm129" id="Text32" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm130">Chair, Straight</label>
                <input name="SingleForm130" id="Text33" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm131">Clock, Grandfather</label>
                <input name="SingleForm131" id="Text34" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm132">Day Bed</label>
                <input name="SingleForm132" id="Text35" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm133">Desk, Small</label>
                <input name="SingleForm133" id="Text36" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm134">Desk, Secretary</label>
                <input name="SingleForm134" id="Text37" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm135">Foot Stool</label>
                <input name="SingleForm135" id="Text38" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm136">Hide-a-bed or Studio Couch</label>
                <input name="SingleForm136" id="Text39" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm137">Lamp, Floor or Pole</label>
                <input name="SingleForm137" id="Text40" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm138">Music Cabinet</label>
                <input name="SingleForm138" id="Text41" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm139">Rug, Large Roll</label>
                <input name="SingleForm139" id="Text42" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm140">Rug, Small Roll</label>
                <input name="SingleForm140" id="Text43" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm141">Sofa, 2 Cushions</label>
                <input name="SingleForm141" id="Text44" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm142">Sofa, 3 Cushions</label>
                <input name="SingleForm142" id="Text45" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm143">Sofa, 4 Cushions</label>
                <input name="SingleForm143" id="Text46" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm144">Sofa, Sectional</label>
                <input name="SingleForm144" id="Text47" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="rowItem">
                <label for="SingleForm145">Table, Coffee, End or Night</label>
                <input name="SingleForm145" id="Text48" class="inputText" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I think I better undertsand your issue, and it is much simpler than what I thought initially

Try these css :

```
<style charset="utf-8" type="text/css">

.rowItem{float:left;}
.col2 .rowItem{width:49.9%;}
.col4 .rowItem{width:24.9%;}
.col6 .rowItem{width:16.66%;}
.rowItem label {font-size:8px;text-align:right;}
.rowItem label, .rowItem input{float:left;display:block;width:49.9%;margin-bottom:12px;}
</style>
```